# SQL query w/ 2 of the same column

Tags: sql

I want to build a query from a defect database. Each defect has a submission date and a status (open, closed, deferred, etc.) I want my results set to have 3 columns:

```
Date, # bugs w/ Open status, # bugs with Closed status
2012-05-31, 3, 1
2012-06-01, 2, 0
2012-06-02, 3, 2
```

I don't know how to move beyond this query to get what I want:

```
select 
    DEFECT.SUBMITTED_DATE as "Opened", 
    count (DEFECT.SUBMITTED_DATE), 
    DEFECT.STATUS as "Status"
from 
     DEFECT
where 
     DEFECT.STATUS='Open' or DEFECT.STATUS='Fixed'
group by 
     DEFECT.SUBMITTED_DATE
```

Looking for suggestions.

Comment: what three columns do you want?

Comment: what rdbms you are using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL,

```
SELECT  DATE(DEFECT.SUBMITTED_DATE) as `DATE_SUBMITTED`, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN DEFECT.STATUS='Open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `# bugs w/ Open status`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DEFECT.STATUS='Fixed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `# bugs with Closed status`,
FROM     DEFECT
GROUP BY DATE(DEFECT.SUBMITTED_DATE)
```

In TSQL

```
SELECT  CAST(DEFECT.SUBMITTED_DATE as DATE) as [DATE_SUBMITTED], 
        SUM(CASE WHEN DEFECT.STATUS='Open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [# bugs w/ Open status],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DEFECT.STATUS='Fixed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [# bugs with Closed status],
FROM     DEFECT
GROUP BY CAST(DEFECT.SUBMITTED_DATE as DATE)
```

Comment: hmm the where clause seems redundant

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
SELECT DEFECT.SUBMITTED_DATE as DATE_SUBMITTED,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DEFECT.STATUS = 'Open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `# bugs w/ Open status`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DEFECT.STATUS = 'Fixed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `# bugs w/ Open status`
FROM DEFECT
WHERE DEFECT.STATUS IN ('Open', 'Fixed')
GROUP BY DEFECT.SUBMITTED_DATE
```

Comment: @bonCodigo: which doesn't match with the (working) provided query... :) What do you mean ? (btw, I added a comma I forgot)

Comment: it does. OP hasn't anyway provided a table/sample data.. But correct query works.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming MS SQL Server:**

```
SELECT DEFECT.SUBMITTED_DATE as [Date]
,SUM(CASE WHEN DEFECT.STATUS = 'Open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_open
,SUM(CASE WHEN DEFECT.STATUS = 'Fixed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_fixed
FROM DEFECT 
WHERE DEFECT.STATUS IN ('Open' ,'Fixed')
GROUP BY DEFECT.SUBMITTED_DATE
```